# pg_hba.conf file

Tags: database, postgresql

Can somebody please post an original copy of an unedited pg_hba.conf file for postgresql, 9.1, on ubuntu. I screwed it up and can't find an original nor in the position to reinstall.Thank you

Comment: I think, [this](http://serverfault.com/a/152943) link to serverfault.com answer can be useful for you.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the file that ships with it. not where it is, just a new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the only way you can receive this file is when somebody else will run **initdb** on his machine and send the file to you by email or via some hosting.

The **official** way is (documentation says):

> Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database cluster's data directory. A **default pg_hba.conf file is installed when the data directory is initialized by initdb**. It is possible to place the authentication configuration file elsewhere, however; see the hba_file configuration parameter.

**UPDATE:**
Is [this **pg_hba.conf**](http://pastebin.com/SCPMvTh3) (*pastebin.com*) what you was looking for? It's the file I received right now when installed a PostgreSQL 9.1 on Debian 6.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Ubuntu at hand but in most cases there are three rules (all the rest is just comments). On most distributions the method is set to ident.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you run initdb again to create a new database cluster which would have a new pg_hba.conf?